# Jython java call throws exception asking for 2 args when only one arg is coded

Tags: java, python, tomcat, jython

I have an Java method I want to call within my Jython servlet running on tomcat5. It looks like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public School loadByName(String name) {
        List<School> school;
        school = getHibernateTemplate().find("from " + getPersistentClass().getName() + " where name = ?", name);

        return uniqueResult(school);
    }
```

I call it in Jython using:

```
foobar = SchoolDAOHibernate.loadByName('University')
```

It throws an error that says loadByName() expects 2 args; got 1.
What other argument could it be looking for?

If i try to create an instance first such as:

```
foo = com.dc.sports.dao.hibernate.SchoolDaoHibernate()
foo.loadByName('University')
```

The first call throws an exception saying:

> No visible constructors for class (com.dc.sports.dao.hibernate.SchoolDaoHibernate)

I'm assuming this is because it is a private-package:

```
package com.dc.sports.dao.hibernate;

...

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
class SchoolDaoHibernate extends AbstractDaoHibernate<School> implements SchoolDao {
```

So how can I get at the method?

Comment: I added a little more information on why I tried call the method staticly.

Answer (score 2):

loadByName is not static.
You need a instance to call it.

```
sdh = SchoolDAOHibernate(...) # ... any args for construction ??
sdh.loadByName('Univeristy') # 2 args :-) self (sdh) and 'University'
```

clearer ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `loadByName` method isn't static, Jython might be expecting the first argument to be an instance of `SchoolDAOHibernate`. If it makes sense for your design, make that method static.